# How can I add some system specific version dll in assembly when build from command line?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, nuget, .net-assembly

How can I add some system specific version dll in assembly when build from command line?

For example:

```
dotnet build -dll System.ComponentModel.Annotations4.0.10.0
```

and after build target directory contain System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll.

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem. please expand on why you want this

Comment: System dlls used during compile after sometimes/often "reference assemblies", which are assemblies without code, only metadata. Similar to a header file in C/C++. Therefore there's no benefit to copying these files to your build's output directory. Like Daniel A. White said, this sounds like an XY problem.